# Can't use multiple ElementTree fromstring statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I might be doing this the completely wrong way, but I'm new to ElementTree and XML namespaces. I'm working with an eBay API response and I am trying to obtain multiple pieces of data from the same XML response. I first tried several `for` statements, like:

```
for i in ET.fromstring(response.text, parser=parser).findall('.//{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC'):
    print(i.text)
for x in ET.fromstring(response.text, parser=parser).findall('.//{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}Title'):
    print(x.text)
```

So with this, the first for statement works fine - it gets all the data I need. But the second returns an error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: parsing finished: line 2, column 13941
```

So I thought, ok - lets try this from a different angle. I went with this code:

```
for x in ET.fromstring(response.text, parser=parser):
    one = x.findall('.//{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC')
    two = x.findall('.//{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}Title')
    print(one, two)
```

So this returned a load of 'Elements', so at first I was like - great! Example below:

```
[<Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC' at 0x03BFF8A0>, <Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC' at 0x03BFFB40>, <Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC' at 0x03BFFDE0>, <Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UPC' at 0x03C020C0> etc...
```

So I figured this is the right approach to getting multiple pieces of data from the same XML source. However, since I'm not doing `x.text` I'm not actually getting the data, just the Element. And I realised doing `print(one.text)` does not work.

So my question is, am I on the right path here, and secondly, how do I get multiple pieces of data from the XML response - or, convert those Elements into the data I need?

Comment: `findall` returns a list. You need to process each item in the list.

Comment: Gotcha! I've got it working now. Thanks very much :)